# I need query to pair every item in a table, with every other item, but only once

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a set of Locations in a table like so:

```
╔═══════════╗
║ Locations ║
╠═══════════╣
║ A         ║
║ B         ║
║ C         ║
╚═══════════╝
```

And I want to match every location in the table against every other location in the table, where the locations are not the same, currently I use this query.

`SELECT 
    a.PostCode AS X,
    b.PostCode AS Y 
FROM locations a 
JOIN locations b 
WHERE a.Location_ID != b.Location_ID;`

And this returns a result set like this.

```
╔═══╦═══╗
║ X ║ Y ║
╠═══╬═══╣
║ B ║ A ║
║ C ║ A ║
║ A ║ B ║
║ C ║ B ║
║ A ║ C ║
║ B ║ C ║
╚═══╩═══╝
```

Which is not really what I need, as for my purposes the pairs (B, A) and (A, B) are the same, I would like to know if there is a way to use an SQL query (MYSQL) to produce a result set like so:

```
╔═══╦═══╗
║ X ║ Y ║
╠═══╬═══╣
║ B ║ A ║
║ C ║ A ║
║ C ║ B ║
╚═══╩═══╝
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change your `where` condition to `>`:

```
SELECT a.PostCode AS X,
       b.PostCode AS Y 
FROM locations a CROSS JOIN 
     locations b 
WHERE a.Location_ID > b.Location_ID;
```

When you don't have an `ON` clause, you should use `CROSS JOIN`.  MySQL is the only database that allows other `JOIN`s not to have an `ON` clause.

Comment: +1 for *MySQL is the only database that allows other JOINs not to have an ON clause*, and [**Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/775d4/2)